# HP Envy 5660 Won't Print

Tags: virtualbox, printing, hp

I have an HP Envy 5660 All-in-One printer. Until I installed a Windows 10 VM in VirtualBox. After setting up the printer in the VM, I printed a document, and all was well. I switched back to the host Ubuntu Zesty machine to print another document. The printer returns no error messages, but appears to try several times to print, to no avail. I deleted the printer in the Ubuntu host, and reinstalled, with no luck. When I went back to the Win VM, it also won't print though the HP manager shows the printer and details -- as does the Ubuntu host.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you using hplip?

Comment: Yep. I don't know, one way or the other, but I can't help but think that installing the full software suite on the Win 10 VM did something on the printer side.

Comment: so this just needs hplip 3.14. What about deleting the existing HP icon from the PRINTERS folder; click ADD top-left of that folder; let the system find the 5660 and see if it can reconfigure for you; HP https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/KnowledgeBase/Troubleshooting/BasicHPLIPTroubleshooting suggest running `hp-check`to check; and `hp-setup` is another way to set up the printer